# href not working in Firefox and opera

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, css, opera

I am using Css3 effects to make my menu look fancier , no issues with that however , I dont know for some strange reasons , when I click on the menu items , they dont redirect to desired pages ie my href="abc.aspx" wont work in Firefox , Opera , but works well in Chrome.Here is the Css3 code which I use

```
#Menu a:active,
#Menu a.active:before,#Menu a:hover:before
{
    Content: ' ';
    position:absolute;
    z-index:-1;
    width:0px;
    height:0px;
    left:50%;
    top:50%;
    border-radius:50%;
    box-shadow:0 0 35px 30px #ADD7E7;

}
```

My menu looks something [image: like this]

However when I remove that Css3 styling , the href works.Can anybody help me out with this as to why this happens.
Any suggestions are welcome.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem may stem from styling `#Menu a:active` together with the pseudo elements. Try separating them or even just remove `#Menu a:active` from the definition altogether. Then you can set your `z-index` back to `-1`  as it will only be being applied to the pseudo element.

I've set up a [jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/3u75x/).

Comment: thanks alot , it works , but in opera if I set the position of my a element to relative the effect moves towards the left side as I stated earlier and if I set li element to relative the the effect appears fine but then href doesnt work.Sorry for all the trouble.Thanks a lot.

Comment: by setting the z-index 1 of the 'a' element and on the active state style , it worked fine , and also I used position relative for li element for the effect to be centered on opera.All is fine for now.Thanks a lot , much appreciated for your time.Thanks man.

Answer (score 2):

It is most likely because of this line in your css:

```
z-index:-1;
```

The default layer is `0` of the document but since on hover you are setting it to `-1`, you won't be able to click on it.

Comment: so should I set it to some positive number or so.Will that solve my issue.

Comment: @freebird: Yes use positive number, apply accordingly for example parent controller and that element so that you are able to click it.

Comment: so do you mean that I should set a higher z-index on hover , so that it can be clickable.

Comment: can you help me on this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10477517/css3-box-shadow-effect-not-working-in-opera/10477782#10477782 if possible

Comment: @freebird: Just play with z-index. For example the parent element which contains your menu, give it `z-index` of 1, and your menu `0`. Also note that for `z-index` to work, you also need to apply `position` for example `position:relative;`

Comment: will try that , did you check my other question.thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

The `z-index:-1` places the element behind the body. As such, it can't be clicked because the body is obscuring it.

This is however a little ambiguous if you haven't defined a background colour for the body, as transparent background colours may not catch clicks.

Avoid negative z-indices. They can go pretty much as high as you want in the positive numbers, more reliably then negative.

Comment: ya I have not defined background color for my body , what can I do for this now.

Comment: As I said, use positive `z-index`. If you need to have something behind something else, put a bigger `z-index` on that "something else".

Comment: I did that my linl has a z-index of 50 , on hover I make it 100 , that is working for me in firefox , but not in opera.

Comment: order version of opera have problem in supporting z-index... which version are u using...