# CSS3 box shadow effect not working in opera

Tags: css, opera

I am having a menu which uses Css3 effects on its hover and active state.The menu looks like this[image]

Here is the Css3 styling I use

```
#Menu a:active,
#Menu a.active:before,#Menu a:hover:before
{
    Content: ' ';
    position:absolute;
    z-index:51;
    width:0px;
    height:0px;
    left:50%;
    top:50%;
    box-shadow:0 0 35px 30px #ADD7E7;
    -moz-box-shadow:0 0 35px 30px  #ADD7E7;
    -webkit-box-shadow:0 0 35px 30px  #ADD7E7;
    border-radius:50%;


}
```

This works in Firefox and Chrome , but doesnot work in opera , I have no idea , can anybody help me out with this.Any help is much appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Which version of Opera are you using?

Comment: Are you using the latest version of opera (10.5+)? It should support the regular "box-shadow" if so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems Opera needs the pseudo element to have a width and height (other than `0px`).
Just tried the following code in Opera 11.62 and it appeared to work.

```
#Menu a:active,
#Menu a.active:before,#Menu a:hover:before
{
    Content: '';
    position:absolute;
    z-index:51;
    width:1px;
    height:1px;
    left:50%;
    top:50%;
    background: #ADD7E7;
    box-shadow:0 0 35px 30px #ADD7E7;
    -moz-box-shadow:0 0 35px 30px  #ADD7E7;
    -o-box-shadow:0 0 35px 30px  #ADD7E7;
    border-radius:50%;
}
```

Comment: ya it worked thanks for your help , but an issue seems to be there the effect , i mean the glowing effect is not well positioned.any help for that

Comment: Have you set the position on your `a` element to `relative`?

Comment: ya I have , did you notice the effect I mentioned.

Comment: got it , the position of my li element I set it to relative and not on my a element , it worked for me , thanks a lot. could you assist me with this if possible http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10477175/href-not-working-in-firefox-and-opera

Answer (score 1):

Try this code

HTML

```
<div class="shadow-bringer shadow"> HI ! Welcome. </div>
```

CSS

```
.shadow-bringer {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #FFFFA2;
    height: 100px;
    margin: 20px auto;
    padding: 5px;
    width: 100px;
}
.shadow {
    box-shadow: 0 0 8px #CCCCCC;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px #ccc;/* for mozila*/
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px #ccc;
    /* For IE upto 5.5 not for 9*/
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(color='#cccccc', Direction=45, Strength=3)
progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(color='#cccccc', Direction=135, Strength=3)
progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(color='#cccccc', Direction=225, Strength=3)
progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(color='#cccccc', Direction=315, Strength=3);
}
```

For more info visit :
1.http://webdesignergeeks.com/tutorials/html-css-tutorials/cross-browser-drop-shadow-for-all-side/

2.http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-box-shadow/

Comment: @freebird you can find fix for all cross browsers. use it in your css

Comment: it is using a div in the example you mentioned but I need to style my a tag.

Comment: @freebird as i think your css code is perfect for opera shadow, which version of opera are you using ?

Comment: its 11.62 , what can I do to achieve that

Comment: @freebird can you able to see shadow on this page http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-box-shadow/ ,  if yes then your css code might have prob if no then your browser issue

Comment: it worked for me , see magicalex's answer.Thanks a lot for your help.Can you assist me with this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10477175/href-not-working-in-firefox-and-opera

Answer (score 0):

According css3please, this should work :

```
.box_shadow {
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px 0px #ffffff; /* Saf3-4, iOS 4.0.2 - 4.2, Android 2.3+ */
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px 0px #ffffff; /* Opera 10.5, IE9, FF4+, Chrome 6+, iOS 5 */
}
```

Check whether this works in your opera : http://css3please.com/